# Javascript getElementById but keep old value

Tags: javascript

I have a file_field_tag inside a rails form with a select file field:

```
<%= file_field_tag "attachments[media_files][]", multiple: true, id: "files" %>
```

And I have an area to preview the images/videos and remove if need be:

```
<span id="result"></span>
```

Everything is working correct but there is only one glitch.... If the images/videos are in separate folders, I have to add the files from one folder first and then from the other folder. The files show at the preview, but after this process only the second batch of files gets saved when I submit the form.
Here is the javascript for all of the above:

```
window.onload = function(){
    if(window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader)
    {

        var filesInput = document.getElementById("files");


        filesInput.addEventListener("change", function(event){


            var files = event.target.files; 
            var output = document.getElementById("result");

            for(var i = 0; i< files.length; i++)
            {
                var file = files[i];

                if (!file.type.match(/.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp4|avi|flv|wmv|mov|tiff|bmp|exif)$/i))
                     continue;

                var picReader = new FileReader();

                picReader.addEventListener("load",function(event){

                    var picFile = event.target;

                    var span = document.createElement("span");

                    span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', picFile.result, '" title="', picFile.name, '"/><span class="remove_img_preview"></span>'].join('');



                    output.insertBefore(span,null);
                    span.children[1].addEventListener("click", function(event){
                        span.parentNode.removeChild(span);
                    });

                });

                picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }

        });
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Your browser does not support File API");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it `input type ='file'`?

Comment: Can you provide more of a code example?  You could use localStorage, or indexDB to store each value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @brk , yes that is correct the input is `input type ='file'`

Comment: @Theopap tru by this `<input type="file" name="img" multiple>` you can upload multiple file at once

Comment: @brk I do have the input set as multiple: true, it's a rails input field.. btw I uploaded the full code.

Comment: *I'm doing `var filesInput = document.getElementById("file");` to get the value from the input with the id file* That won't work, you're getting the `input` DOM element, not the `value` of it.

Comment: thanks for the reply @Harry Chilinguerian I just aded the full code

Comment: @connexo Meant not the value but the actual file. sorry. How can I get the previous file and the new one?

Comment: You're also not getting the *actual file*! Can you please take more care as of how you word stuff? Otherwise your statements about what you're doing are misleading, and thus, instead of adding value to your question, they actually destroy it.

Comment: @Theopap, can you store the old value in the different variable and replace the existing input with the new? So you can use these both when you want to post.

Comment: @thanks Vinod Kolla kind of new with javascript! how can I implement what u suggested in the above code I have?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve you could just save the files into an array variable:

```js
////////////////////////////////
// Create an array for the files somewhere
var fileCache = [];
////////////////////////////////

window.onload = function(){
    if(window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader)
    {

        var filesInput = document.getElementById("files");


        filesInput.addEventListener("change", function(event){


            var files = event.target.files; 
            var output = document.getElementById("result");

            for(var i = 0; i< files.length; i++)
            {
                var file = files[i];
    

                if (!file.type.match(/.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp4|avi|flv|wmv|mov|tiff|bmp|exif)$/i))
                     continue;
      
    ////////////////////////////////
    // Add each file to the array as you process it
    fileCache.push(file);
    ////////////////////////////////

                var picReader = new FileReader();

                picReader.addEventListener("load",function(event){

                    var picFile = event.target;

                    var span = document.createElement("span");

                    span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', picFile.result, '" title="', picFile.name, '"/><span class="remove_img_preview"></span>'].join('');



                    output.insertBefore(span,null);
                    span.children[1].addEventListener("click", function(event){
                        span.parentNode.removeChild(span);
                    });

                });

                picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Your browser does not support File API");
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="files" />
```

Generally, I would avoid using a random global variable, but without knowing exactly what you want to do with the list of files this is the most generic answer.

Comment: Thanks fro the reply @Ricardo Reyna, I've updated my question to exactly what i want. Unfortunately with the answer you provided it has the same behavior as before